# How to show layered navigation in both left and content area in Magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.8, customizing, layered-navigation

We have a layered navigation in magento. I've styled it and everything is ok.

We just want another layered navigation below the toolbar and above the products but just for single filters like Price, Manufacturer and Color as Dropdowns.

I tried very hard to find a solution but the solutions are just for changing the position of the layered navigation.

I hope one of you can help me.

Answer (score 0):

You cant able to figure Layered Navigation in both the side.
If you configure both the sides its showing index(you can use only one index) error